# Autorização em class libraries

Tags: c#, design-pattern, dll

**Dúvida**

Estou com um projeto em que toda a regra de negócio está encapsulada em um conjunto de DLL's com arquitetura em 3 camadas.

Gostaria de saber, qual é a melhor abordagem para o controle de autorização nestas dll's. É possível utilizar o Identity? Existe algum design pattern ou alguma outra abordagem mais indicada para solucionar este problema?

Levando em consideração que um usuário pode ter um perfil com acesso a determinadas funcionalidades (métodos ou classes).

Inicialmente, implementei uma tabela de funcionalidades e uma tabela de perfil que contem estas funcionalidades. Na aplicação, um *Attribute* acima de métodos ou de classes indica qual funcionalidade pode acessar o código.

Para verificar se o usuário pode acessar o código, é verificado se o perfil deste tem a funcionalidade descrita no *Attribute*. Contudo, não tenho certeza de que esta forma é a mais elegante para a situação.

**Arquitetura**

A arquitetura da solução está implementada de acordo com a arquitetura Onion. A camada *Service* encapsula toda a regra de negócio do sistema e tem acesso ao *Domain* e aos *Repositorios*.

O projeto Web (MVC) e Web Api possuem acesso a DLL Services, e o controle de acesso entra neste momento. Para evitar que estes e os demais projetos externos que queiram acessar os Services implementem cada um seus controles de autorização, foi criado um controle de acesso conforme descrito abaixo.

**Código atual**

```
AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ControleAcessoAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string[] funcionalidades;
    private UsuarioAutenticado usuario;

    public ControleAcessoAttribute(params string[] funcionalidades)
    {
        this.funcionalidades = funcionalidades;
        this.usuario = UsuarioAutenticado.GetInstance();
        VerificarAcesso();
    }

    public void VerificarAcesso()
    {
        var isAutorizado = VerificarFuncionalidades();
        if(!isAutorizado)
        {
            throw new NegocioException("O usuário autenticado não possui permissão para acessar esta funcionalidade.");
        }
    }

    public bool VerificarFuncionalidades()
    {
        foreach (var item in usuario.Perfil.Funcoes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < funcionalidades.Length; i++)
            {
                if(item.Descricao.Contains(funcionalidades[i]))
                    return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Método de utilização

```
public class Foo
{
      [ControleAcesso("Bar","Foo")]
      public void Bar()
      {
           //Some code here
      }
}
```

**Um outro problema**

Um outro problema que estou enfrentando é em saber qual é o usuário autenticado nas aplicações, uma vez que o projeto web pode implementar Session e outros não. Esta autenticação deveria ser responsabilidade da DLL? O mais correto seria guardar a autenticação no banco de dados?

Comment: Vinícius, vou reabrir sua pergunta por considerar que há a possibilidade de obter uma boa resposta. Porém sugiro ainda que edite a questão colocando algum trecho de código que exemplifique sua abordagem. Abraço!

Comment: Irei editar a pergunta com o código existente hoje e a arquitetura utilizada nas DLL's!

Answer (score 7):

## Gostaria de saber, qual é a melhor abordagem para o controle de autorização nestas dll's. É possível utilizar o Identity?

É possível, mas o Identity foi pensado para a arquitetura MVC, inicialmente. Funcionará bem se o fluxo da sua camada de serviços for parecido com um *Controller*.

## Existe algum design pattern ou alguma outra abordagem mais indicada para solucionar este problema?

Depende do que você precisa. Aproveitando o gancho da sua implementação por *Attribute* passando funcionalidades por parâmetro, a aproximação é correta, mas tenho algumas observações:

`Strings` são mais propensas a problemas em algum momento (principalmente os problemas de digitação). Ao invés de usar:

```
[ControleAcesso("Bar","Foo")]
```

Crie um Enum de funcionalidade:

```
public enum Funcionalidade {
    Foo, Bar
}
```

Passe eles como parâmetro:

```
[ControleAcesso(Funcionalidade.Bar, Funcionalidade.Foo)]
```

`VerificarFuncionalidades` poderá ser simplificado e ficará mais eficiente e mais seguro em termos de código.

Sobre `Sessions`, você terá que escrever um controle próprio de sessões, visto que você não está usando solução pronta de alguma arquitetura conhecida.

Sobre onde guardar estes dados, acho que é uma parte opinativa da questão. Por balanceamento de carga, prefiro manter no banco de dados ou usando alguma cache chave-valor, como o Redis, por exemplo.

Comment: Irei incrementar a pergunta então com o código que tenho hoje

Comment: @Vinícius Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: inicialmente estava com enum mas este estava muito grande. O enum estava enumerando as chaves das funcões cadastradas no banco de dados. Você acha essa abordagem correta?

Comment: @Vinícius Mais segura, eu diria. Que fique grande. Melhor assim do que algo propenso a erro.